# Angular Observables vs Promise CRUD and refreshing data

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a few questions regarding angular 2/4 pattern for simple crud application. Most the examples I've viewed, I don't see how the data is refreshed after insert/updating, etc..

I'm a bit new with Observables but understand most of the pattern with the exception with refreshing data after an insert/update/delete. Can someone explain the best way to refresh data and do I really need to use Observables instead of promises ? Is it accepted to still use promises?

How do I do the following below with Observables?

**users.service**

```
insertPromise(user : User)
{
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url = this.baseUrl;

    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(user),options)          
          .do(data=>console.log(JSON.stringify(data))) 
          .toPromise()
          .then(this.extractPromiseData)          
          .catch(this.handleError);
}

insertObservable(user : User) {

    this.usersService.insert(user)
      .subscribe(
      resp => {

        console.log(resp);
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

**user-list.component** (Contains refresh after insert)

```
insert(user: User)
{
     this.usersService.insertPromise(user)
         .then(result=>console.log(result))
         .then(
           ()=>this.usersService.getAllUsers()
           .then(
             users=>

             this.users = users

             )
           .catch(error=>console.log(error))           
           )
         .catch(error=>console.log(error));
}

insertObservable(user: User)
  {

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url = this.baseUrl;

     return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(user),options)
          .map((response: Response) => response.json())
          .do(data=>console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))  
          .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your implementation. You can, for example, return the new user in response to `POST` request, then put this user data into `this.users`. Another option is to reload the whole list after any successful `POST`/`PUT`. I think the first method is better, as it doesn’t cause any additional HTTP requests. Code example:

```typescript
insert(user: User) {
  const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  const url = this.baseUrl;

  return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(user), options)          
    .do(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))) 
    // first, convert HTTP response to User instance (easier if User is
    // just an interface, harder if it’s a class)
    .map(response => response.json().user as User)
    // then, push that User object to the existing array of users
    // then you don’t have to “refresh” this.users, because it’s already
    // up to date
    .map(user => this.users.push(user))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: yeah reloading just the modified/new user makes sense but how would I load the entire list, which I'm not going to do but just for reference. 

then for put should i just look for the user and set  that user to the updated user. For delete  should i just remove the user then?

Comment: Actually I figured it out, I'm using PrimeNG DataTable and noticed it only works with the spread operator which is new to me but once I changed my code its working as expected.  Thanks for the help!!

         let users = [...this.users];
         users.push(user);
         this.users = users;

Comment: Perhaps that DataTable only detects change when it receives a new object (array) and the spread operator apparently creates a new array.